# How to simulate Background App Termination on iPhoneX

Tags: ios

A procedure is available for other iPhone but nothing available on iPhoneX.

For info, here is the procedure with other (real) iphone:

- Press the home button to enter the app to background.
- Long press the power button until you see “slide to power off”.
- Release the power button and long press the home button for about 5s (until you see your home screen reappeared).

Comment: Did you figure out how to do that? Because I need to simulate that now.